# Why does my python for loop colon get a syntax error?

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax-error

Why does my python for loop colon get a syntax error?

```
a=int(input("Enter a number.")
for x in range(a):
    print(" ")
c=int(input("Enter another number.")
for x in range(c):
    print("x")
```

Comment: You're not closing off your `int` function calls...

Answer (score 2):

This issue is only a missing parenthesis on the input line: 
`a=int(input("Enter a number.")` and `c=int(input("Enter another number.")`

```
a=int(input("Enter a number."))
for x in range(a):
    print(" ")
c=int(input("Enter another number."))
for x in range(c):
    print("x")
```

Comment: This is not related to the issue but I will suggest to use `xrange`  and `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

not_a_robot is right.

Also, in the second loop, you're not even printing the value of the x variable, just an "x".

```
a=int(input("Enter a number."))
c=int(input("Enter another number."))
...
for x in range(c):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple typo in your code, see a,c declarations where you have missed closing one more parenthesis.

```
a=int(input("Enter a number."))
for x in range(a):
    print(" ")
c=int(input("Enter another number."))
for x in range(c):
    print("x")
```

Hope that helps.